# html password field return empty in django1.9

Tags: python, django, html, django-views

i developing django app name called "login" for user registration and login page

- i created an html page register.html it contains form with user name and password field, form method "post"
- when i submit form, password field always coming empty even when i typed in that field

login.views.py

```
def submitreport(request):
errors=[]
if request.method =='POST':
    if not request.POST.get('m_id', ''):
        errors.append('Enter a m_id.')
    if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
        errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
    if not request.POST.get('passcode', ''):  #this triggered even when i typed
        errors.append('Enter password')
    if not errors:
        m_id= request.POST.get('id', '')
        Email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        password =request.POST.get('passcode','')
        print(password)
        user = User.objects.create_user(m_id,Email,password)
        messages.success(request, "Successfully registered")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
return render(request, 'login/register.html',{'errors': errors})
```

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>  
{% if errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
 {% endif %}
 <form action="{% url 'login:submitreport' %}" method="post">
    <p>Machine id : <input type="text" name="m_id" value="{{ m_id }}"></p>
    <p>e-mail (optional): <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ email }}"></p>
    <p>password: <input type="password" name="psw" value="{{ passcode }}"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @doru thanks for fast response,it works!

Comment: You can then accept my answer by checking it to close the question.

Comment: You should be using Django forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have in your view:

```
password =request.POST.get('psw','')
```

not

```
password =request.POST.get('passcode','')
```

Comment: django takes post value from name ,then why value="{{ xx}}" ?

Comment: @VigneshVicky Is this a question?

Comment: @VigneshVicky through the `value` attribute you can set a default value to that field which you can send from django. This a `HTML` thing.

Comment: oh,so need to send as template context

Comment: @VigneshVicky yes, you can put it in the template context. The better solution is to use the Django [`forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/) framework which takes care of lot of stuff for you.